# database does not exist - PostgreSQL in Server Side Swift using Vapor 3 and Fluent

Tags: swift, postgresql, fluent, vapor, server-side-swift

I'm writing a web service in Swift using Vapor 3. I'm using `FluentPostgreSQL` for data persistence. I have a user model which conforms to both `PostgreSQLModel, PostgreSQLMigration`. The app builds correctly. However, when I run the app, I am getting the following error.

```
Fatal error: Error raised at top level: ⚠️ PostgreSQL Error: database "trialService" does not exist
- id: PostgreSQLError.server.fatal.InitPostgres
```

This is how my `configure.swift` looks like.

```
try services.register(FluentPostgreSQLProvider())

let configPSQL = PostgreSQLDatabaseConfig(hostname: "localhost", username: "imthath", database: "trialService")
let psql = PostgreSQLDatabase(config: configPSQL)

var databases = DatabasesConfig()
databases.add(database: sqlite, as: .sqlite)
databases.add(database: psql, as: .psql)
services.register(databases)
```

As you can see I was earlier using SQLite and now I am trying to use PostgreSQL for some models including User. I did not get any error when I was only SQLite.

Comment: As an alternative, a tool such as `Postico` can be used to create a database. And then run `vapor run migrate` in terminal.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create the database from the terminal before your Vapor app can connect to it:

```
createdb trialService
```